# python pyqt matplotlib computation GUI app plotting wrong

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt4

everyone!
I am working on a project to use python pyqt4 to design a GUI for computing V-I curves of PV panel. I want to input the required parameter and compute the PV panel output current and use matplotlib to plot the V-I curve.
My code work well. However, I found that the curve I get from the app is wrong, while directly compute it is right. The computation methods are exactly same. But when I put the computation in GUI is different.
The code is here:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
q = 1.6 * (10 ** -19)
k = 1.38 * (10 ** -23)
Tref = 25
Eg = 1.1

def calReverseSaturationCurrent(Isc,Voc,Ns,A,Tc):
    a = np.exp(q*Voc/(Ns*k*A*Tc))-1
    return Isc/a
def calSaturationCurrent(Irs,Tc,A):
    return Irs*((Tc/Tref)**3)*np.exp(q*Eg*(1/Tref - 1/Tc)/(k*A))
def calPhotocurrent(Isc,Ki,Tc,insolation):
    return (Isc + Ki*(Tc-Tref))*insolation
def calOutputCurrent(Isc,Voc,Ns,A,Tc,Ki,insolation,Np,Rs,Rsh,V):
    Irs = calReverseSaturationCurrent(Isc,Voc,Ns,A,Tc)
    Is = calSaturationCurrent(Irs,Tc,A)
    Iph = calPhotocurrent(Isc,Ki,Tc,insolation)
    I0 = 0
    I = np.array([])
    def f(ii,*arg):
        temp_v = arg[0]
        return ii - Np*Iph+Np*Is*(np.exp(q*(temp_v/Ns+ii*Rs/Np)/(k*Tc*A))-1)
    for vv in V:
        ii=fsolve(f,I0,args=vv)
        I = np.append(I,ii)
    return I
class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()
    def initUI(self):

        self.figure = plt.figure()
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)

        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self)
        self.toolbar.hide()

        self.idealFactor = QtGui.QLabel('Ideal Factor A')
        self.shortCircuitCurrent = QtGui.QLabel('Short Circuit Current')
        self.openCircuitVoltage = QtGui.QLabel('Open Circuit Voltage')
        self.temperatureCoefficient = QtGui.QLabel('Temperature Coefficient')
        self.seriesCells = QtGui.QLabel('Series Cells')
        self.parallelCells = QtGui.QLabel('Parallel Cells')
        self.seriesResistance = QtGui.QLabel('Series Resistance')
        self.shuntResistance = QtGui.QLabel('Shunt Resistance')
        self.outputVoltageMin = QtGui.QLabel('Min Output Voltage')
        self.outputVoltageMax = QtGui.QLabel('Max Output Voltage')
        self.workingTemperature = QtGui.QLabel('Working Temperature')
        self.isolation = QtGui.QLabel('Isolation')

        self.idealFactorEdit = QtGui.QDoubleSpinBox()
        self.idealFactorEdit.setValue(1.0)
        self.shortCircuitCurrentEdit = QtGui.QDoubleSpinBox()
        self.shortCircuitCurrentEdit.setValue(3.17)
        self.openCircuitVoltageEdit = QtGui.QDoubleSpinBox()
        self.openCircuitVoltageEdit.setValue(21.8)
        self.temperatureCoefficientEdit = QtGui.QDoubleSpinBox()
        self.temperatureCoefficientEdit.setValue(0.065)
        self.seriesCellsEdit = QtGui.QDoubleSpinBox()
        self.seriesCellsEdit.setValue(36.0)
        self.parallelCellsEdit = QtGui.QDoubleSpinBox()
        self.parallelCellsEdit.setValue(1.0)
        self.seriesResistanceEdit = QtGui.QDoubleSpinBox()
        self.seriesResistanceEdit.setValue(0.1)
        self.shuntResistanceEdit = QtGui.QDoubleSpinBox()
        self.shuntResistanceEdit.setValue(float("inf"))
        self.outputVoltageMinEdit = QtGui.QDoubleSpinBox()
        self.outputVoltageMinEdit.setValue(8)
        self.outputVoltageMaxEdit = QtGui.QDoubleSpinBox()
        self.outputVoltageMaxEdit.setValue(11)
        self.workingTemperatureEdit = QtGui.QDoubleSpinBox()
        self.workingTemperatureEdit.setValue(25)
        self.isolationEdit = QtGui.QDoubleSpinBox()
        self.isolationEdit.setValue(1)

        self.calBtn = QtGui.QPushButton('Get V-I',self)
        self.calBtn.clicked.connect(self.getVI)

        grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(grid)

        grid.addWidget(self.idealFactor, 1, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.idealFactorEdit, 1, 1)

        grid.addWidget(self.shortCircuitCurrent, 1, 2)
        grid.addWidget(self.shortCircuitCurrentEdit, 1, 3)

        grid.addWidget(self.openCircuitVoltage, 2, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.openCircuitVoltageEdit, 2, 1)

        grid.addWidget(self.temperatureCoefficient, 2, 2)
        grid.addWidget(self.temperatureCoefficientEdit, 2, 3)

        grid.addWidget(self.seriesCells, 3, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.seriesCellsEdit, 3, 1)

        grid.addWidget(self.parallelCells, 3, 2)
        grid.addWidget(self.parallelCellsEdit, 3, 3)

        grid.addWidget(self.seriesResistance, 4, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.seriesResistanceEdit, 4, 1)

        grid.addWidget(self.shuntResistance, 4, 2)
        grid.addWidget(self.shuntResistanceEdit, 4, 3)

        grid.addWidget(self.outputVoltageMax, 5, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.outputVoltageMaxEdit, 5, 1)

        grid.addWidget(self.outputVoltageMin, 5, 2)
        grid.addWidget(self.outputVoltageMinEdit, 5, 3)

        grid.addWidget(self.workingTemperature, 6, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.workingTemperatureEdit, 6, 1)

        grid.addWidget(self.isolation, 6, 2)
        grid.addWidget(self.isolationEdit, 6, 3)

        grid.addWidget(self.calBtn, 7,0)
        grid.addWidget(self.canvas, 8, 0, 6, 0)


        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 1000, 800)
        self.setWindowTitle('PYPV')
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('pvPanel.png'))        

        self.show()

    def getVI(self):
        A = self.idealFactorEdit.value()
        Isc = self.shortCircuitCurrentEdit.value()
        Voc = self.openCircuitVoltageEdit.value()
        Ki = self.temperatureCoefficientEdit.value()
        Ns = self.seriesCellsEdit.value()
        Np = self.parallelCellsEdit.value()
        Rs = self.seriesResistanceEdit.value()
        Rsh = self.shuntResistanceEdit.value()
        Vmin = self.outputVoltageMinEdit.value()
        Vmax = self.outputVoltageMaxEdit.value()
        V = np.linspace(Vmin,Vmax,1000)
        Tc = self.workingTemperatureEdit.value()
        insolation = self.isolationEdit.value()
        I = calOutputCurrent(Isc,Voc,Ns,A,Tc,Ki,insolation,Np,Rs,Rsh,V)
        plt.cla()
        ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        ax.plot(V,I)
        self.canvas.draw()


def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am sure that the computing method is right. I tested without the GUI. The result is fine. The code is below:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

q = 1.6 * (10 ** -19)
k = 1.38 * (10 ** -23)
Tref = 25
Eg = 1.1
A = 1.0
V = np.linspace(8,11,1000)
Isc = 3.17
Ki = 0.07
Ns = 36.0
Np = 1.0
Voc = 21.8
Rs = 0.1
#Rsh = float("inf")
Tc = 25
insolation = 1

def calReverseSaturationCurrent(Isc,Voc,Ns,A,Tc):
    a = np.exp(q*Voc/(Ns*k*A*Tc))-1
    return Isc/a

def calSaturationCurrent(Irs,Tc,A):
    return Irs*((Tc/Tref)**3)*np.exp(q*Eg*(1/Tref - 1/Tc)/(k*A))

def calPhotocurrent(Isc,Ki,Tc,insolation):
    return (Isc + Ki*(Tc-Tref))*insolation

def calOutputCurrent(Isc,Voc,Ns,A,Tc,Ki,insolation,Np,Rs,Rsh,V):
    Irs = calReverseSaturationCurrent(Isc,Voc,Ns,A,Tc)
    Is = calSaturationCurrent(Irs,Tc,A)
    Iph = calPhotocurrent(Isc,Ki,Tc,insolation)
    I0 = 0
    I = np.array([])
    def f(ii,*arg):
        temp_v = arg[0]
        return ii - Np*Iph+Np*Is*(np.exp(q*(temp_v/Ns+ii*Rs/Np)/(k*Tc*A))-1)
    for vv in V:
        ii=fsolve(f,I0,args=vv)
        I = np.append(I,ii)
    return I

def makePlots(I,V):
    plt.plot(V,I)
    plt.show()

def test():
    I = calOutputCurrent(Isc,Voc,Ns,A,Tc,Ki,insolation,Np,Rs,Rsh,V)
    makePlots(I,V)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()
```

Below are the two plots:
[Without using GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92ODO.png)
[With GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXsSq.png)

English is not my first language. I hope I describe the problem well.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you use Python-2, where the `/` operator behaves differently for integers than for floats. In the first case it is an integer-division: the result is an integer and the remainder is discarded. In the second case it is what you would typically expect from division. This is a source of many bugs so in Python-3 the `/` operator is always a regular division (returning a float), and the integer-division can be done with `//`. For more details see [PEP-238](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/). Note that your `calSaturationCurrent` function contains such an integer division: `1/Tc` yields 0 in Python-2.

To make Python-2 behave like Python 3 you can use a 'future-import'. If you add the following line at the top of your program (before your other import statements) you will get the same results with and without GUI.

```
from __future__ import division
```

Now, you probably also used Python-2 for your non-GUI version, so why did you get different results in the first place? My best guess is that in the gui-version of your program, the values you get from Qt are slightly different (far behind the decimal point that is). The fact that your program is susceptible for this indicates it may have bugs.

For instance, if you print the result of the `calSaturationCurrent` function,  it is 3.42723507299e-122 without GUI, and 0.0 with the GUI. This means that the function `f`, whose roots you are trying to solve, is always very close to 0 or exactly 0. I would not trust the results, and would start by making a plot of `f` itself.

Comment: Thank you so much! After I change Tc=25.0, I get the right result! I learned a lot from your answer.

Comment: Glad to be of help. Please mark the question as 'Answered'.